# How to remove Items from a list with the same property value, where the count is greater than 2

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc

I have List of Jo Cards, i want to remove Job Cards where the `VehicleID` `count` is greater than two

Here is My Attempt.

```
var OpenJobCards = await _context.WorkshopJobCards.Include(wjc => wjc.WorkshopJobCardCategory).Where(wjc => wjc.Job_Card_Closed == false).ToListAsync() ;
OpenJobCards.Remove(OpenJobCards.GroupBy(wjc => wjc.VehicleID).Count() >2);
```

Comment: For stuff like this is *very* important to see your models. Are you wanting to remove  jobs where other jobs have the same `VehicleID` or is `VehicleID` some sort of collection, and you want to remove jobs where there's multiple items in `VehicleID`?

Comment: The limit of Job Cards that can be Opened on a Vehicle is 2, therefore i want the user to only open a Job Card on a Vehicle that has only less than 2 Job Cards open. Those vehicles will be passed to the user and and he/she can open a Job Card for only those vehicles. That is why I am removing Vehicles that have 2 Job Cards already Opened.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your comment, it would seem you're actually looking at this the wrong way. If vehicles have a collection of job cards, and your ultimate goal is to show only vehicles with less than 2 job cards assigned to them, then just do:

```
var vehicles = await _context.Vehicles.Where(x => x.JobCards.Count() < 2).ToListAsync();
```

Done.

Answer (score 1):

as far as I understand you are using DBContext. If it is so, please also keep in mind that it is better to use Queriable where possible so that filtering is done on the DB side and does not fetched into your application memory

```
var listToRemove = await _context.WorkshopJobCards.Include(wjc => wjc.WorkshopJobCardCategory)
     .Where(wjc => wjc.Job_Card_Closed == false).GroupBy(wjc => wjc.VehicleID)
     .Where(t => t.Count() >2)
     .Select(x => new OpenJobCard() {Id = x.Key});

_context.entity.RemoveRange(listToRemove);
```

Comment: `RemoveRange(listToRemove)`  "takes two parameters `index` and `count`"

Comment: Thank You Very much. I wasn't aware about the IQueriable i had used IEnumarable in all my One to Many relationships on my Models. Much appreciate the advise